# How to append a string to dataframe column which is list in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with one column, "value", that contains a list of string, for example

```
id    value
001   ["abc", "abd"]
002   ["xyz"]
003   []
```

I need append another string to "value", the result would be

```
id    value
001   ["abc", "abd", "new"]
002   ["xyz", "new"]
003   ["new"]
```

Anyone know how to achieve this in pyspark? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` the array with an array of one literal string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('value', F.concat(F.col('value'), F.array(F.lit('new'))))
```